# Зациклить progressbar DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

**Как сделать:** что бы - progressbar, по нажатию на кнопку, работал без остановки и после окончания цикла - заполнить прогресс бар на 100% и остановить. ?

**В коде:**

**Min и Max** - это свойства отвечающие за диапазон значений.

**Position** - позиция, на которой находится в данный момент индикатор.

**i** - переменная для перебора целых чисел.

**Label** - показывает какое сейчас обрабатывается число.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   i, proc, Max : integer;
begin
    Max := 50000;
   for i:=0 to Max do
     begin
       proc := ((i * 100) div Max);
       Label1.Caption := IntToStr(i);
       ProgressBar1.Position := proc ;
       Application.ProcessMessages;
// Тут нужный цикл
........................................................

.........................................................


// И после окончания цикла - заполнить прогресс бар на 100% и остановить.
         end;
    end;
```

**То есть простыми словами, говоря** - Сделать "бесконечный" прогресс-бар, который просто показывает, что процесс закачки идёт и после окончания цикла остановить его.

Comment: Вам нужно значение прогрессбара высчитывать и обновлять внутри цвела

Comment: @JVic, А если, просто, сделать его бесконечным, в начале цикла и в окончании просто остановить ?. То есть, что бы он, просто для вида -показывал что процесс идет.

Comment: тогда просто перед цbклом `proc := 0;` внутри цикла `inc(proc); ProgressBar1.Position := proc ;`  так же можете добавить обнуление `if (proc = 100)  then poc = 0;`

Comment: @JVic, Спасибо, получилось. Но по правде сказать, скорость работы, за этого, упала.

Comment: сделайте обновление прогрессбара раз в сто итераций `if (i div 100) then обновить бар`

Comment: @JVic, Спасибо, так быстрее!

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать свойство `Smooth`, со значениями `true` или `false` в зависимости что вам нужно, этот режим предназначен специально для таких случаев как у вас!